# Running Silverlight unit tests in Visual Studio Online

Tags: unit-testing, silverlight, azure-devops

I'm in the process of moving from on-premise TFS to Visual Studio Online (VSTS) and I'm trying to create a new CI build definition as our local one is xaml based.

For our server based tests I'm using a Visual Studio Test task it it's running fine.

I also need to run Silverlight tests (as we currently have in the local xaml build). Currently I can run my SL unit tests from the command line and output a .trx test results file using the following command:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\StatLight\statlight.exe" -x .\path-to-silverlight.xap --ReportOutputFileType:TRX -r=.\statlight-results.trx`

I can also run this using a CommandLine task in vsts (I'm already using a local build agent instead of a hosted one), but I don't know how to:

1. Get it to fail the build if there's a failing test.
2. Get the test results into the Test output tab in vsts.

I'll also need to do something similar to fail a build based on js unit tests as we migrate away from Silverlight, so the solution for the SL tests may help with running js tests also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if there is a switch that causes the command line to return the number of failed tests. If so you can use the return code to fail your build. Any value other than zero will fail build.

As for test results just add a publish test results task and point to the generated trx file. That is it.

Comment: I was copying the output trx into the TestResults folder - will try the Publish Test Results Task. Thanks for the suggestions - I'll see what kind of return codes I can get.